# My bootstrap website is displaying anormally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and I was trying to create a navbar, the problem is that when I opened the live server to see how it was going, this appeared on the screen:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDYyH.png)

Instead of this which ​was I expecting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3zgq.png)

So, can you help me please?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="">brand</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Boostrap version 4.3.1 because the classes you're using seem to belong to that version. This works:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="">brand</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using version 3.4.1 of bootstrap, all you have to do is to replace the bootstrap link with one of these versions v4.0.0 or 4.1.x

cdn link available on this page: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/